# Marshaling a reference to a char** array

Tags: dll, pinvoke, marshalling

I am having trouble marshaling an array of char* by reference. The data is filled in correctly on the C++ unmanaged side. But when its returned by referernce to the managed side, I end up with a single pointer to the first array element.

```
//The function in C++
extern "C" DATAACCESSLAYERDLL_API void  __stdcall DB_SchemaField_GetKeyValues(Schema::TSchemaFieldHandle hField, const char** &keys, const char ** &values)
{
    Schema::CSchemaField *pField = CDataObjectFactory::GetObjectTpl<Schema::CSchemaField>(hField);
    if (!pField) return;
    Schema::TSchemaKeyValuePair::iterator itor = pField->GetKeyValues().begin();

    int index = 0;
    for (itor; itor != pField->GetKeyValues().end(); ++itor)
    {
        keys[index] = (*itor).first.c_str();
        values[index] = (*itor).second.c_str();
        index++;
    }

    return;
}
```

The pInvoke declaration

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
[DllImport("DataCore.dll")]
static private extern void DB_SchemaField_GetKeyValues(Int64 pField, 
    [In, Out] ref IntPtr[] keys, [In, Out] ref IntPtr[] values);
```

And finally.... the code which marshals

```
    int keyValueCount = DB_SchemaField_GetKeyValuesCount(GetHandle());
    if (keyValueCount > 0)
    {
        IntPtr[] KeysPtr = new IntPtr[keyValueCount];
        IntPtr[] ValuesPtr = new IntPtr[keyValueCount];

        DB_SchemaField_GetKeyValues(GetHandle(), ref KeysPtr, ref ValuesPtr);
        for (int i = 0; i < keyValueCount; i++)
        {
            string key = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(KeysPtr[i]);
            string value = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ValuesPtr[i]);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                KeyValues.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you passing the `char**` by reference? I would remove that. `const char**` on the unmanaged side and `[Out] IntPtr[]` on the managed side.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think he is returning a reference to an array of strings, not a pointer to a string. So `const char** &` is still the correct signature.

Comment: @KendallFrey No. He's passing in an array of `const char*` which is being populated by the unmanaged code. The ref is erroneous. Notice that in the managed code there is never an assignment `keys = ...`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, I wasn't aware that P/Invoke would marshal back an array that was not passed by ref.

Comment: @KendallFrey It's done as per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake to pass the two `const char*` arrays by reference. That's one level of indirection too far for the marshaller. You need the following:

**C++**

```
extern "C" DATAACCESSLAYERDLL_API void  __stdcall DB_SchemaField_GetKeyValues(
    Schema::TSchemaFieldHandle hField, const char** keys, const char ** values)
```

**C#**

```
[System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()]
[DllImport("DataCore.dll")]
static private extern void DB_SchemaField_GetKeyValues(Int64 pField, 
    [Out] IntPtr[] keys, [Out] IntPtr[] values);
```

You'd better make sure you use the pointers that are returned immediately, because the C string returned by `c_str()` is only valid until the next modification of the `std::string` object.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `string` instead of `IntPtr`?

Comment: This seems to work! I didn't realise we could do it this way. Thank you :)

Comment: Care to explain why? That's not what I would have expected.

Comment: @KendallFrey Even if you can persuade the marshaller to marshal them as such (and I don't know if you can for an array), it will call `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointers that are returned. Which is an error.